# C++ Linux IDE that imports makefiles and runs boost unit tests

Tags: c++, linux, ide

I am looking for an C++ IDE for Linux (other than Vim or Emacs :) ) that would automatically import a makefile (even better - automakefile), be able to compile the sources and on top of it run boost unit tests.

I have tried QT Creator, but it doesn't seem to import makefiles, and KDevelop which imports makefiles fine, but I couldn't figure out how to run unit tests.

I would be grateful for suggestions. Please let me know how to use the functionality I am after if its not obvious :)

Comment: I think eclipse can do that. Have you tried it?

Comment: What version of QtCreator?? Support for Makefiles is somehow recent (within the last year or so), but newer versions of QtCreator do support makefiles

Comment: @David, I found the support for makefiles (inspired by @tdammers reply), and it works fine. I still didn't figure out how to run unit tests efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

Hazarding a guess: eclipse?

I know for a fact that you can use eclipse as a C++ IDE (I do), and I'm reasonably certain that there would be some plugin available for automake and boost.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491380/boost-test-and-eclipse/3778246#3778246) is a related answer to a different question that deals with parsing the boost test ouput in eclipse. The makefile project is also simple, create a new c/c++ empty makefile project in the same directory where the root Makefile is.

Answer (score 1):

Try http://www.codeblocks.org/

Comment: I managed to load the code fine, but how do I run the unit tests?

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure it can. I didn't use boost unit tests at all.

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans might be able to do it. In any case, it can import existing projects with a makefile; not sure about the rest of your requirements though.

Comment: Hi, how can I import makefiles? I am looking just now and I can't see this option...

Comment: Well, you can open existing projects: Go to File > New Project, select C/C++ and then C/C++ Project With Existing Sources. This should load your sources and headers as well as the makefile into a new netbeans project.

Comment: Ahhh, I didn't think of creating a new project :)

Comment: I managed to open the project and it builds fine, but now I can't find how to run the unit tests

Comment: As I said, I have no idea about boost unit tests. I generally whip up my own; netbeans might not support them after all.