# Controlling output of Boost.Test source location format

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost-test, output-formatting, catch2

[Catch2](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2) and [Boost.Test](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/test/doc/html/index.html) provide similar features for writing unit tests.
For a certain project I have to use Boost.Test instead of Catch2.
The problem I have is that both use different format outputs.

For example, Catch2 will say that the was a fail in

`test.cpp:9`

(see example below).
However Boost.Test will say

`test.cpp(9): error in ...`.

This format doesn't allow my editor to recognize the output as a source location.

**Is there way to make Boost.Test output the source location as `file.ext:lineno` instead of `file.ext(lineno)`?**

This is a typical output for Catch2

```
----------------------------------------------
Testing Binary Search
----------------------------------------------
test.cpp:9
..............................................test.cpp:18: FAILED:
  REQUIRE( binary_search(arr, 176) == 0 )
with expansion:
  -1 == 0==============================================
test cases: 1 | 1 failed
assertions: 5 | 4 passed | 1 failed
```

This is a typical output for Boost.Test

```
Running 7 test cases...
./layout.hpp(764): error: in "layout_to_offset_1d_nontrivial": check L[3] == &B[3] - base(B) has failed [3 != 6]
Running 7 test cases...
./.././detail/layout.hpp(764): error: in "layout_to_offset_1d_nontrivial": check L[3] == &B[3] - base(B) has failed [3 != 6]

*** 1 failure is detected in the test module "C++ Unit Tests for Multi layout"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution in this historical post: https://richarddingwall.name/2008/06/01/using-the-boost-unit-test-framework-with-xcode-3

Using the (lost of) art of virtual function override and Boost.Test fixtures:

Simply add this code (some updates to the original post, with minor formats and C++11 updates):

```
#include<boost/test/output/compiler_log_formatter.hpp>

struct xcode_log_formatter: boost::unit_test::output::compiler_log_formatter{
    // Produces an Xcode-friendly message prefix.
    void print_prefix(std::ostream& output, boost::unit_test::const_string file_name, std::size_t line) override{
        output << file_name << ':' << line << ": error: ";
    }
};

// Set up the unit test framework to use an xcode-friendly log formatter.
struct xcode_config{
    xcode_config(){boost::unit_test::unit_test_log.set_formatter(new xcode_log_formatter);}
};

// Call our fixture.
BOOST_GLOBAL_FIXTURE(xcode_config);
```

with this change the output looks like (note file:lineno format).

```
Running 7 test cases...
./layout.hpp:781: error: error: in "layout_to_offset_1d_nontrivial": check L[3] == &B[3] - base(B) has failed [3 != 6]
Running 7 test cases...
./.././detail/layout.hpp:781: error: error: in "layout_to_offset_1d_nontrivial": check L[3] == &B[3] - base(B) has failed [3 != 6]
```

I am still interested in simpler solutions.

---

Here it is a more compact version of this code, renamed for my own case (xcode->gedit):

```
#include<boost/test/output/compiler_log_formatter.hpp>
struct gedit_config{
    struct formatter : boost::unit_test::output::compiler_log_formatter{
        void print_prefix(std::ostream& out, boost::unit_test::const_string file, std::size_t line){
            out<< file <<':'<< line <<": ";
        }
    };
    gedit_config(){boost::unit_test::unit_test_log.set_formatter(new formatter);}
};
BOOST_GLOBAL_FIXTURE(gedit_config);
```